# Using "already" for time sequence

Tags: time

I wrote this sentence:

> Now, suppose that the "Price" anchor is **already** visited and the "ShippingInfo" anchor is visited **after that**. At this time, the context node "Product", which is defined as the "Common Ancestor" of these two anchors, is retrieved and its associated node in the page, which is the lowest common ancestor of the anchor elements, is obtained.

Does my usage of "already" and "after that" to convey a sequence in time is correct?

For example:

> suppose this neighborhood is already visited and that neighborhood is visited after that. Now we can ...

How about:

> Suppose this neighborhood is already visited and that neighborhood is visited **next**. Now we can ...

Answer (score 1):

No. You can say

> this neighborhood **was** visited **first** and that neighborhood **was**
>   visited next.

or

> this neighborhood **is usually** visited **first** and that neighborhood **is usually**
>   visited next.

or

> **when** that
>   neighborhood **was** visited, this neighborhood **had  been** visited **already**.

depending on what you want to say.

Comment: Can I say "*Now, suppose that this neighborhood **has been** already visited and the other one is going to be visited. At this time....*" Actually I want to refer to the time we visit the second neighborhood, when the previous one has been visited.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to achive. Give me more context, the full paragraph.

Comment: the exact scenario is technical, suppose in a tree structure an action depends on visiting two specific nodes. I want to say to the reader, suppose the first node has been visited and the second node is visited, now the action is performed..

Comment: Why not to say then: _when both nodes are visited, the action is performed_? Or, if the order is important, say: _when node A and then node B are visited, the action is performed_.

Comment: I came up with this *Suppose that A has been visited. When visiting B, the action is performed*. Because I want to say action is exactly done when the first condition is met (visiting A) and the second condition is provided (visiting B).

Comment: What about, *Suppose that A has been visited. At the time B is visited, the action performed...*?

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it really is. Why do you suggest to _suppose_? Just descrie the actual rule: if -> then. Does it matter that A is visited before B, or B can be visited first? If yes, say _when B is visited after A the action is immediately performed_. If the order does not matter, just say _when both A and B are visited the action is immediately performed_.